# What does "Normal" mean in the context of linear equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My summer packet has the question:

"Write equations of the line through the given point a)parallel and b) normal to the given
 line: $(−6, 2)$, $5x + 2y = 7$"

I had no problem with finding the equation for the line that is parallel, but I have no idea what "normal" is supposed to mean.

Comment: It means "perpendicular" to the given line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal is another word for "perpendicular".

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I've never heard of perpendicular being called "normal" before!